# OpenGL Texture Usage

Tags: c++, opengl

[image: Picture]

So recently I started reading through OpenGL wiki articles. This is how I picture OpenGL texturing described from [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture). Though, several points are not clear yet.

Will following statements be true, false or depends?

1. Binding two textures to same texture unit is impossible.
2. Binding two samplers to same texture unit is impossible.
3. Binding one texture to two different texture units is impossible.
4. Binding one sampler to two different texture units is impossible.
5. It is application's responsibility to be clear about what sampler type is passed to what uniform variable.
6. It is shader program's responsibility to make sure to take sampler as correct type of uniform variable.
7. number of texture units are large enough. Let each mesh loaded to application occupy as much texture unit as it please.
8. Some Sampler parameters are duplicate of texture parameters. They will override texture parameter setting.
9. Some Sampler parameters are duplicate of sampler description in shader program. Shader program's description will override samplers parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going through your statements in the following. Sometimes I will argue with quotes from the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf). None of that is specific to GL 4.5, I just chose it because that is the most recent version.

> **1. Binding two textures to same texture unit is 
>   impossible.**

If I'd say "false", it would be probably misleading. The exact statement would be "Binding two textures to the same target of the same texture unit is impossible." Technically, you can say, bind a 2D texture and a 3D texture to the same unit. But you cannot *use* both in the same draw call. Note that this is a dynamic error condition which depends on what values you set the sampler uniforms to. Quote from section 7.10 "Samplers" of the GL spec:

> It is not allowed to have variables of different sampler types
>   pointing to the same texture image unit within a program object. This
>   situation can only be detected at the next rendering command issued
>   which triggers shader invocations, and an `INVALID_OPERATION` error will
>   then be generated.

So the GL will detect this error condition as soon as you actually try to draw something (or otherwise trigger shader invocations) with that shaders while you configured it such that two sampler uniforms reference different targets of the same unit. But it is not an error before. If you temporarily set both uniforms to the same value but do not try to draw in that state, no error is ever generated.

> **2. Binding two samplers to same texture unit is impossible.**

You probably mean [Sampler Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object) (as opposed to just "sampler" types in GLSL), so this is true.

> **3. Binding one texture to two different texture units is impossible.**

False. You can bind the same texture object to as many units as there are available. However, that is quite a useless operation. Back in the days of the fixed-function pipeline, there were some corner cases where this was of limited use. For example, I've saw someone binding the same texture twice and use register combiners to multiply both together, because he needed some square operation. However, with shaders, you can sample the texture once and do anything you want with the result, so there is really no use case left for this.

> **4. Binding one sampler to two different texture units is impossible.**

False. A single sampler object can be referenced by multiple texture units. You can just create a sampler object for each sampling state you need, no need to create redundant ones.

> **5. It is application's responsibility to be clear about what sampler type is passed to what uniform variable.**
>
> **6. It is shader program's responsibility to make sure to take sampler as correct type of uniform variable.**

I'm not really sure what exaclty you are asking here. The sampler variable in your shader selectes the texture target and must also match the internal data fromat of the texture object you want to use (i.e. for `isampler` or `usampler`, you'll need unnormalized integer texture formats otherwise results are undefined).

But I don't know what "what sampler type is passed to what uniform variable" is supposed to mean here. As far as the GL client side is concerned, the opaque sampler uniforms are just something which can be set to the index of the texture unit which is to be used, and that is done as an integer via `glUniform1i` or the like. There is no "sampler type" passed to a uniform variable.

> **7. number of texture units are large enough. Let each mesh loaded to application occupy as much texture unit as it please.**

Not in the general case. The required `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` (which defines how many different texture units a fragment shader can access) by the GL 4.5 spec is just 16. (There are separate limits per shder stage, so there is `GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`, `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` and so on. They are all required to be at least 16 in the current spec.)

Usually, you have to switch textures inbetween draw calls. The usage of [array textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) and [texture atlasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) might allow one to further reduce the number of necessary state switches (and, ultimately, draw calls).

Very modern GPUs also support [GL_ARB_bindless_texture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/bindless_texture.txt), which completely bypasses the "texture unit" layer of indirection and allows the shader to directly reference a texture object by some opaque handle (which basically boils down to referencing some virtual GPU memory address under the hood). However, that feature is not yet part of the OpenGL standard.

> **8. Some Sampler parameters are duplicate of texture parameters. They will override texture parameter setting.**

Yes. Traditionally, there were no separate sampler objects in the GL. Instead, the sampler states like filtering or wrap modes were part of the texture object itself. But modern hardware does not operate this way, so the sampler objects API has been introduced as the [`GL_ARB_sampler_objects`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sampler_objects.txt) extension (nowadays, a core feature of GL). If a sampler object is bound to a texture unit, its settings will override the sampler state present in the texture object.

> **9. Some Sampler parameters are duplicate of sampler description in shader program. Shader program's description will override samplers parameters.**

I'm not sure what you mean by that. What "sampler descripitons" does a shader program define? There is only the declaration of the uniform and possibly the initialization via `layout(binding=...)`. However, that is just the initial value. The client can update that any time by setting the uniform to another value, so that is not really "overriding" anything. But I'm not sure if you mean that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not distinguishing sampler object and sampler in glsl. By shader 'program's description' I meant shader types(sampler1D, sampler2D, sampler3D, ... ), because I thought application will set which target the sampler will look into in texture unit before passing it to shader program, and that is stored as parameter. I guess that was wrong? shader object is only reference to texture unit, and "which target is used" is only decided by what type(sampler1D, ..) glsl gave to that sampler. Is it going to right direction?